# I need find a solution for a SQL query

Tags: sql, oracle, group-by

I need some help to list all fields and only purchases in November from the INGREDIENT table and the INGREDIENT_PURCHASE_LIST table
the total amount for each item. Order the result set by the descending date ordered.

```
CREATE TABLE ingredient
(
 ingredient_id NUMBER(4,0) PRIMARY KEY,
 ingredient_name VARCHAR2(100) NOT NULL
);



CREATE TABLE ingredient_purchase_list
(    
 ing_pl_id NUMBER(4,0) PRIMARY KEY, 
 date_ordered  DATE ,
 quantity VARCHAR2(15),
 unit VARCHAR(15),
 unit_price  NUMBER(4,2) NOT NULL,
 ingredient_id NUMBER(4,0),   
   CONSTRAINT ingredient_id_fk  FOREIGN KEY (ingredient_id)
   REFERENCES ingredient (ingredient_id));
```

I have this:

```
 SELECT i.ingredient_id, i.ingredient_name, ip.date_ordered, ip.quantity, ip.unit, ip.unit_price, (SUM(ip.unit_price * ip.quantity)) "TOTAL" 
 FROM ingredient_purchase_list ip, ingredient i
 WHERE ip.date_ordered BETWEEN '11-01-2019' AND '11-30-2019';
 GROUP BY ip.date_ordered;
```

I got this error:

> ORA-00937: not a single-group group function

[This is the original query](https://i.stack.imgur.com/e2hQo.png)

Comment: Notice you have `;` separating your where and group by. And when using group by you need to group it by your selected field.

Answer (score 0):

I found 2 issues.

> 1. There's a broken link between your 2 tables
> 2. include those non-aggreated columns in your group by list

```
SELECT i.ingredient_id, i.ingredient_name, ip.date_ordered, ip.quantity, ip.unit
    , ip.unit_price, (SUM(ip.unit_price * ip.quantity)) "TOTAL" 
FROM ingredient_purchase_list ip
INNER JOIN ingredient i on i.ingredient_id = ip.ingredient_id
WHERE ip.date_ordered BETWEEN '11-01-2019' AND '11-30-2019'
GROUP BY ip.date_ordered, i.ingredient_id, i.ingredient_name, ip.quantity, ip.unit
    , ip.unit_price;
```

Comment: @Tiz, try again

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit ambiguous.  It sounds like you want one row per ingredient.  It is unclear what "total amount for each item means", so lets do both the total price and quantity.

Then, if you want the totals, what is the "date ordered"?  There can be multiple dates.  So, let me interpret this as "most recent date ordered".

Your query is simply missing the `JOIN`.  *Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  **Always use proper, explicit, standard `JOIN` syntax.**:

```
SELECT i.ingredient_id, i.ingredient_name, 
       SUM(ip.quantity) as total_quantity,
       SUM(ip.unit_price * ip.quantity) as total_price
FROM ingredient_purchase_list ip JOIN
     ingredient i
     ON i.ingredient_id = ip.ingredient_id
WHERE ip.date_ordered >= DATE '2019-11-01' AND
      ip.date_ordered < DATE '2019-12-01'
GROUP BY ip.date_ordered, i.ingredient_name
ORDER BY MAX(ip.date_ordered);
```

Finally, you'll notice that I changed the date logic.  The Oracle `date` datatype has a time component -- which is often invisible in query results.  To be safe, use inequality logic rather than `between`, so you don't miss results from the last day of the month.

Comment: Thank you so much Gordon